# Reference request: probability that d numbers are coprime

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, pr.probability

The following theorem can be found in Hardy-Wright (Theorem 459), except that they state it only for $d=2$. Do you know of a reference where the proof of this general statement is written?

**Theorem:** *Let $d\ge2$ be an integer. Let $F$ be a bounded subset of $\Bbb R^d$. For every positive real number $r$, denote by $F(r)$ the set of points $x$ of $\Bbb Z^d$ such that $x\over r$ belongs to $F$. Assume that the cardinality of $F(r)$ divided by $r^d$ converges to some non-zero limit when $r$ goes to infinity. Then, when $r$ goes to infinity, the cardinality of the set of $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$'s in $F(r)$ such that $\operatorname{GCD}(x_1,\ldots,x_d)=1$ is equivalent to $r^d/\zeta(d)$ when $r$ goes to infinity.*

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Thank you Daniele for the editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^d$ with $d \geq 2$. We define $F_r := rF \cap \mathbb Z^d$ for any real number $r>0$ and assume that the limit
$$
 \mathcal V(F) := \lim_{r \to + \infty} \frac{|F_r|}{r^d}
$$
exists (for convex subsets, this is the Lebesgue volume of $F$). We rewrite the proof of Theorem 459 of Hardy–Wright so that it yields the following more general result.

*If $\mathcal V(F)$ is well-defined, then we have*
$$
  \lim_{r \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{\left| \left\{ x \in F_r, \operatorname{gcd}(x_1, \cdots, x_d) = 1 \right\} \right|}{r^d} = \frac{\mathcal V(F)}{\zeta(d)}.
$$

**Proof.**
We can and will assume that $0 \notin F$, which will not change any of the limits.
We also fix $N$ such that $F \subset [-N,N]^d$.

For every rational $r>0$, let $f(r) = \left| \left\{ x \in F_r, \operatorname{gcd}(x_1, \cdots, x_d) = 1 \right\} \right|$. As $0 \notin F$, $|F_r| = f(r)=0$ when $r<1/N$ and $f(r) \leq |F_r| \leq (2rN+1)^d \leq (3rN)^d$ for all $r \geq 1/N$, so $|F_r| \leq (3rN)^d$ in all cases.  For any point $x$ of $F_r$, there is a unique integer $k \in \mathbb N$ such that the gcd of the coordinates of $x$ is $k$, and then $x/k$ contributes to  $f(r/k)$. Consequently (the right-hand side being in fact a finite sum)
$$
  |F_r| = \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} f(r/k).
 $$
By Möbius inversion, we then get
$$
 f(r) = \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \mu(k) |F_{r/k}|.
$$

The sum of $\mu(k)/k^d$ converges absolutely towards $1/\zeta(d)$ as $d \geq 2$, so
$$
 \frac{f(r)}{r^d} - \frac{\mathcal V(F)}{\zeta(d)} = \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{\mu(k)}{k^d} \left( \frac{|F_{r/k}|}{(r/k)^d} - \mathcal V(F) \right).
$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. By definition of $\mathcal V(F)$, we fix $n_0$ such that if $r/k \geq n_0$, $\left| \frac{|F_{r/k}|}{(r/k)^d} - \mathcal V(F) \right| \leq \varepsilon$, which gives the inequality
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor r/n_0 \rfloor} \frac{1}{k^d} \left| \frac{|F_{r/k}|}{(r/k)^d} - \mathcal V(F) \right| \leq \zeta(d) \varepsilon.
$$

On the other hand, the bounds on $|F_{r/k}|$ give
$$
 \sum_{k > \lfloor r/n_0 \rfloor} \frac{1}{k^d} \left| \frac{|F_{r/k}|}{(r/k)^d} - \mathcal V(F) \right| \leq \left((3N)^d + \mathcal V(F)\right) \times \frac{ (\lfloor r/n_0 \rfloor)^{1-d} }{d-1}.
$$
Hence, for $r$ large enough, the absolute value of $\left|\frac{f(r)}{r^d} - \frac{\mathcal V(F)}{\zeta(d)}\right|$ is smaller than $2 \zeta(d) \varepsilon$, which proves the desired convergence. $\blacksquare$

*Acknowledgements.* This post greatly benefitted from exchanges with Samuel Le Fourn.

Answer (score 3):

The proof for general $n \geq 2$ is the same as the $n = 2$ case. For simplicity we shall consider the region $F = [1,X]^n$ where $X$ is some large positive number. We put $F_d$ be the subset of $F \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ consisting of those tuples whose coordinates are all divisible by $d$. Note that $d \leq X$, by definition.

We see that

$$\displaystyle |F_d| = \frac{X^n}{d^n} + O \left(\frac{X^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}}\right).$$

We now write $F^\ast$ for the subset of $F$ consisting of those tuples whose coordinates are co-prime. Then

$$\begin{align*} |F^\ast| & = \sum_{d \leq X} \mu(d) |F_d| \\
& = \sum_{d \leq X} \mu(d) \left(\frac{X^n}{d^{n}} + O \left(\frac{X^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}} \right) \right)\\
& = \prod_{p \leq X} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n}\right) X^n + O \left(\sum_{d \leq X} \frac{X^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}}\right) \\
& = \prod_p \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n} \right) X^n + O \left(X^{n-1} \log X \right) \end{align*}. $$

To be more explicit, we consider the product

$$ \begin{align*} \prod_{p} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n} \right) & = \prod_{p \leq X} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n} \right)\prod_{p > X} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n} \right)  \\
& = \prod_{p \leq X} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n} \right) \left(\exp \left(\sum_{p > X} \log \left(1 - p^{-n} \right) \right) \right) \\
& = \prod_{p \leq X} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^n} \right)\left(1 + O(X^{1-n})\right) \end{align*}$$

which justifies the first previous calculaton.

Finally, by the Euler product of the Riemann zeta function we have $\zeta(n)^{-1} = \prod_{p} (1 - p^{-n})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Stanley. I agree that the same proof works. However, I am not looking for a proof but for a place where it is written so that I can refer to it in a paper: it really is a reference request rather than a mathematical question. Also, I do want the fully general statement. Your particular statement is proved here for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07180

Comment: From my answer you should gain the confidence to simply say "this is proved explicitly for $n = 2$ by Hardy and Wright and the general case follows similarly". The first sentence in my answer says essentially the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can find the general idea (Möbius inversion) in he book *Vinogradov, I. M. Elements of number theory Dover Publications Inc., 1954* (Ch. 2.3.d and problem 2.17). But it is written in a strange form.[image]

[image]